# Tool to search for files in multiple ISO files

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, search, iso

Are there any portable, offline, windows (Win XP and above) software that allows end-user to search files hidden in multiple ISO files?

The software is preferable to be gratis (if possible).

Example:

I have 3 ISO files. Each ISO files contain many files inside them. I want to search for, say, "system.dll" but I do not know which ISO file contain this file.

So, I will use this software to search all the three ISO file to see if they contain the file "system.dll".

Suppose that the third ISO file contain the "system.dll" file under the folder name "system\lib\w99". The software will then display it in a list.

If the file "system.dll" is also found in the second ISO under the folder 'backup\android\", then the software should list the two results for me.

if the file "system.dll" is also found in the first ISO inside an archive file called "system.cab" (or any archive files) under the folder "games\world\bin\", then the software should also list this result as well.

Comment: Be aware that if the ISO images are installation images, that the files you search for could be within installation archives/packages. Do you need for your search to also search within these archives, or do you know the files you search for to be ordinary files?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) with an [ISO plugin](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm).

Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>F7</kbd> to search a directory tree. Specify your file name as *.iso and that's it.

As a bonus, you can further refine your search - partial file name, created since a certain date, file size, only current directory, or X levels of sub-directories etc, etc

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try WhereIsIt

http://www.whereisit-soft.com/

The software can search inside ISO files, removable media, archives, ...
Also many plugins are available.

Answer (score 0):

[File Locator Pro](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro)

- once installed, runs offline. I even use the free version in a portable way - not sure if the full version can still do that.
- [runs on](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/requirements) <strike>XP</strike> Vista and higher. I'm not exactly sure when they dropped XP support, maybe it still works but is no longer officially supported.
- searches [ISO files](http://help.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/en/index.html?extension_tab.htm) as well as many other archives
- is not gratis (the gratis version cannot search in ISO files)